# Check if file or folder is "Always available offline"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, offline-caching

How can we check (return true or false) if a folder or file is activated for "Always available offline"? I am using Microsoft Sync Center.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-attribute-constants

Comment: @JamesHill how would that help? The question is about a specific application's settings regarding folders, not a local file's attributes

Comment: using @JamesHill's link and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241247/how-can-i-check-local-onedrive-folder-is-in-sync you might be able to come up with an answer

Comment: @Matt Extract icons? This is total overkill. Also he only talks about folders. I look for files and folders. There must be a much easier way...

Comment: I suppose it would not be too easy either, because it is Sync Center who ads "Always available offline" in drop-down menu. That means that sort of API for Sync Center should be used.

Comment: if anybody interested, I came up after some hours, with a solution myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the need informations by using the WMI provider:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/windows/desktop/offlinefiles/about-offline-files-wmi-provider

EDIT:

Don't forget to add a reference to `System.Management`.

I came up with following snippet:

```
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OfflineFilesItem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {
                var pinInfo = (ManagementBaseObject)m.GetPropertyValue("PinInfo");

                if (pinInfo != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)pinInfo.GetPropertyValue("Pinned"))
                    {
                          //the file or folder is set to "always available offline"
                          var itemPath = m["ItemPath"]
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some code. This answer is only slightly better than posting just the link.

Comment: @Stijn Yes sure but the fun fact is, that the only thing I have gotten here, have been also only links without further explanations. But yeah, there is my solution. Hopefully it will help someone else in the future...