# How can I check status of files/folders in OneDrive folder whether it is synced or not using c# or PowerShell?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, onedrive

I want to check the status (Available when online/ Available on this device) of files residing in OneDrive folder either using C# or PowerShell. I want to check whether file is available on disk, basically check the sync status of files or folder.

[image]

Is there any possible way to get this status?

Comment: Was not able to validate as i am not at my desk, but there seems to be a solution at Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rodneyviana/powershell-cmdlet-to-check-onedrive-for-business-or-onedrive-personal-status

Comment: @An-dir, Thanks for replying. This article is providing information about complete Onedrive folder.I want to check the status of individual folder/files in side this OneDrive folder.

Comment: You should read again. It has a parameter called "bypath" that might do what you expect. it is documented right there: https://github.com/rodneyviana/ODSyncService/tree/master/Binaries/PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dll mentioned in this thread is good, but I don't want to have to distribute that to everyone's machines, so I came up with an alternative. The script that follows would check OneDrive for a folder called Documents and returns its status.

```
# ID 303 = "Availability status" | The status is generally one of the following...
# "Always available on this device", "Available on this device", "Available when online"
$OneDriveDocs = "$env:OneDrive\Documents"
$Shell = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Split-Path $OneDriveDocs))
$Status = $Shell.getDetailsOf($Shell.ParseName((Split-Path $OneDriveDocs -Leaf)),303)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916008) or [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41241247) may be able to help achieve your goal (Sorry if this isn't a real answer, I am unable to comment on posts yet...).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Flexan I tried this method and I'm getting below exception. System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range. (Parameter 'handle')'

Answer (score 0):

Some installations have problems when trying to use the byPath parameter.

You may test if your installations are affected and if the beta is a workaround for you.

Current Version: https://github.com/rodneyviana/ODSyncService/tree/master/Binaries/PowerShell

Beta Version:
https://github.com/rodneyviana/ODSyncService/blob/master/Binaries/Beta/OneDriveLib_OnDemand.zip

```
Unblock-File -Path "C:\ODTool\OneDriveLib.dll" # change path if necessary
Import-Module "C:\ODTool\OneDriveLib.dll"

Get-ChildItem $env:OneDrive | foreach {
$_ | select *,@{Name="ODStatus";Expression={Get-ODStatus -ByPath $_}}
} | Format-Table ODStatus,FullName
```

You may format your output using the "Format-Table"

If you have "OnDemandOrUnknown" often/always then add information to this:
https://github.com/rodneyviana/ODSyncService/issues/36